# TinyMCE, onKeyDown, get current element object

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I am strugling to find a way to get the elements object behind the current cursor position.

I've tried using `onNodeChange` and failed.

Let me explain, when the cursor is moved around the editor using keyboard, I want to send the object of the element that is behind the cursor to another custom function.

Now in tinymce functions like `onMouseDown(ed, e)`, I can send `e` to the custom function and if I do `console.log(e);` it will display the object of the clicked element.

If I use `console.log(e);` within `onNodeChange`, I get the HTML of the element instead of the object.

How to get the object of the current element where the cursor is at? Like I said, this works when clicking using `onMouseDown(ed, e)` but I need something for when the cursor is moved by keyboard.

I am using the latest 3.5.8 version as it comes with WordPress.